# Is it possible to define optional parameters in the middle of cucumber step

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Defining an optional parameter in a cucumber step is easy, if it's in either end of the step. what about if it's in the middle, eg:

```
@When( "^(in)?active update message is received for (\\D+)(?: (\\d))? (\\D+) (\\d+)$" )
public void testStepDef(
        final String optionalInactive,
        final String someWord,
        final int optionalInt,
        final String someOtherWord,
        final int id ) {
```

Example patterns that match:

```
 * inactive update message is received for word anotherword 1   // not ok
 * active update message is received for word 1 anotherword 7   // ok
 * inactive update message is received for word 7 anotherword 3 // ok
```

From those examples, only the latter 2 work; first one, that doesn't define the `optionalInt`, fails. The regex matches, but method invokation fails:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to invoke cucumber.stepdefs.common.CommonStepDefs.testStepDef(String,String,int,String,int) in file:/step/file/location
```

Any way to work around this limitation?

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but you are using primitives for your arguments. An int can't be null. What if you try with Integer type instead. At any rate, I might just move more of that parsing into the step, if cucumber isn't up to it.

Answer (score 2):

As you are just using Regex's you can do whatever a Regex can do. However all you are doing here is making your step definitions incomprehensible.

In general when cuking you want to keep your step definitions as simple as possible. Its far better to have 3 simple step definitions than one complex one.

So the best way to work around this is to write simpler clearer step definitions with as few parameters as possible and the very simplest of regex's.